# How to interpret special characters in command line argument in C?

Tags: c, bash, special-characters, command-line-arguments, argv

First problem:

Suppose we write a simple program which takes in command line arguments and prints to a file. If the user enters

> writetofile Hello!0\n w%orl\t!@#y

bash replies with

> !0: event not
>   found.

Without the user knowing things like using quotes ('') or escape characters ('\'), how do I handle this stuff instead of bash understanding it as a command?

Second problem:

Once I get these arguments, how do I interpret them as special characters and not sequences of characters. (ie. \t is tab, not '\''t')

That is, how do make sure that the program writes this to the file:

```
Hello!0
 w%orl    !@#y
```

and not

```
Hello!0\n w%orl\t!@#y
```

Comment: The first problem is a problem with bash. The second, what have you tried?

Comment: To the second part: Right now, I'm reading character by character. Maybe I should create a buffer when I see a '\'?

Comment: Also, I can't do anything about the first part?

Comment: I mean, there are specific things that bash interprets as commands, such as `!something`, which you can't get it to ignore. I think your safest bet is just telling people to put quotes around it.

Comment: @ask: You can't do anything about the first part, because bash always parses the command line (and hence interprets `!`, `#`, etc) before it even decides to run your program. See [this previous answer](http://superuser.com/questions/552268/trying-to-create-bash-function-which-collects-and-quotes-all-arguments-but-it-d/552355#552355).

Comment: @Xymostech for the specific case of `!something` (i.e. History Expansion), you can disable it with `set +H`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the second problem: as @Jims said, you could use printf(1) to print the string.  Good idea, but be aware that that would work only because the escapes you (appear to) want to recognise, like `\t` and `\n`, are the same as the ones that printf recognises.

These escapes are common, but there's nothing fundamental about them, so the *general* answer to your question – and the answer if you want to recognise an escape that printf doesn't – is for your program to interpret them.  The C-like code to do that would be something like:

```
char *arg = "foo\\tbar\\n"; /* the doubled backslashes are to make this valid C */
int arglen = strlen(arg);
for (i=0; i<arglen; i++) {
    if (arg[i] == '\\') { // we've spotted an escape
        // interpret a backslash escape
        i++; // we should check for EOS here...
        switch (arg[i]) {
          case 'n': putchar('\n'); break;
          case 't': putchar('\t'); break;
          // etc
         }
     } else {
         // ordinary character: just output it
         putchar(arg[i]);
     }
 }
```

(insert error handling and good style, to taste).

Answer (score 2):

You can't get bash to stop parsing a command line as a command line. In your particular case, `set +H` would disable history expansion, thus allowing !0 as a literal, but a command would still fail if you included `(parenthesis)`, `$variables`, `#comments`, `ampersand &` and a dozen other elements of shell syntax.

Note that this only applies to the parsing stage of the shell, not for any data that is passed literally into `execve` or similar.

Either make the user quote the data (`'single quotes'` will take care of everything except other single quotes), or make your program read the data itself so that the interaction goes

> ```
> $ writetofile
> Please enter your gibberish and press enter: Hello!0\n w%orl\t!@#y
> Thank you for your eloquent contribution.
> $
> ```

Answer (score 1):

First problem: Use single quotes. ie: writetofile 'Hello!0\n w%orl\t!@#y'

Second problem: Use printf.