# A way to prevent bash from parsing command line w/out using escape symbols

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, command-line-arguments

I'm looking for a way (other than ".", '.', \.) to use bash (or any other linux shell) while preventing it from parsing parts of command line. The problem seems to be unsolvable
[How to interpret special characters in command line argument in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14922730/how-to-interpret-special-characters-in-command-line-argument-in-c/14924332#14924332)

In theory, a simple switch would suffice (e.g. -x ... telling that the 
string ... won't be interpreted) but it apparently doesn't exist. I wonder whether there is a workaround, hack or idea for solving this problem. The original problem is a script|alias for a program taking youtube URLs (which may contain special characters (&, etc.)) as arguments. This problem is even more difficult: expanding "$1" while preventing shell from interpreting the expanded string -- essentially, expanding "$1" without interpreting its result

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question.  Could you include an example?

Comment: Read the URLs from stdin, not from the command line.

Comment: Reading URLs from stdin is ruled out if you want to automate the task (see the last sentence of my question)

Comment: Reading from stdin is always an option.  That's how pipes work.  If you script can't handle it, you can use `xargs` to make it play nice.

Comment: @Mr.Llama: In general, yes (but in this case I don't see a way to implement this)

Comment: _This problem is even more difficult: expanding $1 while preventing shell from interpreting the expanded string_ – It's not _difficult_ so much as ill-defined. You can turn off some kinds of expansion (like glob expansion), but if you could turn off _all_ expansion then you wouldn't expand `$1`. But natively, bash doesn't do recursive expansion of parameters (except in some arithmetic context). `foo=\$bar; bar=123; echo $foo` -> literal `$bar`. So what's the problem?

Comment: I think I made it more clearer (read the last sentence). It's not ill-defined (as said, a switch could do it)

Comment: @jaamlysi: re your last sentence: just use double-quotes: `"$1"` instead of just `$1`.

Comment: The shell only interprets the _first_ (zeroth) argument as a command. So what, you want to execute the literal `$1`? Or you want to execute a command whose name has whitespace in it?

Comment: Yes but after expanding $1, etc., the rest (special chars like \, &...) gets interpreted as well

Comment: @jaamlysi No they don't; you are misunderstanding what's happening at which step. By the time your script gets `$1`, it's already been parsed (i.e. special characters interpreted), and it's far to late to go back and unparse it. Preventing any further parsing when you use `$1` is easy -- as I said, wrap it in double-quotes (`"$1"`). But this is not the same as undoing the parsing the shell did before it called your script, and there's no way at all to go back and undo that.

Comment: You're going to have to provide an example for which `somealias 'http://...'` isn't sufficient.

Comment: @GordonDavisson If the command line argument to which $x refers gets interpreted before expanding $x, then my "real world problem" is nonsensical. However, the general one is not (as said, a simple switch to prevent the argument from being interpreted would suffice -- but I suppose there's nothing like this in Linux shells). Aside from rewriting the shell, I don't see any other solutions at the moment

Comment: @chepner The first sentence of my question implies that it's sufficient. The problem is that there's no way of retrieving an URL w/ special char-s via a positional parameter ("$1" or whatever)

Comment: And you've been told that quoting `$1` protects any characters that were properly assigned to `$1`.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [here-document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html):

```
myprogramm <<'EOF'
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oT3mCybbhf0
EOF
```

If you wrap the starting `EOF` in single quotes, bash won't interpret any special chars in the here-doc.

Comment: Bash won't interpret special characters in here doc even if EOF is not surrounded by single quotes.

Comment: @OlegAndriyanov - Half correct.  Variables and process substitutions still apply.

Comment: @OlegAndriyanov You are wrong. Bash would interpret the `$string` as variable `string` if the opening EOF is not enclosed in single quotes. Also command substitution, process substitution and arithmetic expansion would happen.

Comment: @hek2mgl That's new to me. Thanks!

Comment: Nice try, but this is equivalent to '.'-ing. See the last 2 sentences of the question for some (more difficult real-world) problem examples

Comment: @jaamlysi I don't get you. Please edit your question and make it more clear. I've showed how to pass youtube links, you requested that. As long as the input does not contain the string `EOF` and the start of a line, the above solution should work with any kind of input.

Comment: Well, I could also use 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oT3mCybbhf0', couldn't I? That's even simpler

Comment: Yes, you can! I don't get the problem

Comment: @hek2mgl As I said, a way other than '... I also revised (the end of) the question to make it clearer (at this point, Gordon Davisson seems to get closest to what I supposed when posting this but I still hope a solution might appear)

Comment: Unfortunately you failed to make question more clear. My answer is, if the program needs arbitrary data as input, read it from stdin and don't use a command line option for that. If you have no control over the program, then write a wrapper which reads from stdin and does the proper escaping.

Comment: While correct, I fail to see how this is better than `myprogram 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oT3mCybbhf0'`.

Comment: @chepner He he! you are right! I've just used an arbitrary youtube link since youtube was mentioned in the question. But this looks like a bad example since youtube is clever, they don't use "problematic" characters in their urls. I admit that after answering this, I more and more failed to get the question. Btw, have you opened the youtube link?

Comment: @hek2mgl Doesn't it? What about https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=204&v=8KmZiVzxAE0?

Comment: @jaamlysi `myprogram 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=204&v=8KmZiVzxAE0'` would work. Note the single quotes

Comment: @hek2mgl `myprogram "https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=204&v=8KmZiVzxAE0"` would also work. Note the double quotes. So?

Comment: @jaamlysi Yeah this would also work unless they put an `$` into the urls. I repeated that many times. So what? I'm still not able to get the problem.

Comment: @hek2mgl Reread the 1st sentence of the question, and the 2 last ones. This should give a pretty good idea of what its all about

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't do it, because the shell parses the command line (and interprets things like "&") before it even gets to the point of deciding your script/alias/whatever is what will be run, let alone the point where your script has any control at all. By the time your script has any influence in the process, it's far too late.

*Within* a script, though, it's easy to avoid most problems: wrap all variable references in double-quotes. For example, rather than `curl -o $outputfile $url` you should use `curl -o "$outputfile" "$url"`. This will prevent the shell from applying any parsing to the contents of the variable(s) before they're passed to the command (/other script/whatever).

But when you run the script, you'll always have to quote or escape anything passed on the command line.

Comment: @hek2mgl Can you be more specific?

Comment: Probably you missed the question - I admit it is hard to get. But passing input to a script without the input getting subject to shell parsing *is* possible using the here-doc solution that I've posted.

Comment: Reverted the downvote because the question appears to be more and more unclear.

Comment: @hek2mgl I'm not totally clear on what the actual question is either, but I'll argue my answer is correct as far as it goes: there's no way to avoid parsing *on the command line*. Your answer avoids this problem by passing the URL via stdin rather than on the command line. But IMO this is mostly useful for the user passing the URL to the script; within the script, double-quotes work great.

Comment: Double quotes won't work, since variables names, command substitution and friends would get expanded. I would use single quotes. But I still think the user cares about passing data *to* the script. ---- IMHO using stdin is the best approach for that. Take the `gpg` command for example which needs to read arbitrary data - it reads from stdin.

Answer (score 0):

Your spec still isn't very clear. As far as I know the problem is you want to completely reinvent how the shell handles arguments. So… you'll have to write your own shell. The basics aren't even that difficult. Here's pseudo-code:

```
while true:
    print prompt
    read input
    command = (first input)
    args = (argparse (rest input))
    child_pid = fork()
    if child_pid == 0: // We are inside child process
        exec(command, args) // See variety of `exec` family functions in posix
    else: // We are inside parent process and child_pid is actual child pid
        wait(child_pid) // See variety of `wait` family functions in posix
```

Your question basically boils down to how that "argparse" function is implemented. If it's just an identity function, then you get no expansion at all. Is that what you want?