# Bash - Special characters on command line

Tags: bash

I am writing a BASH script that generates a password if no argument is provided, and verifies if a password meets specified requirements if one argument is provided.  One of these requirements is to have a special character in the password.

However, I've run into three situations which I am having trouble with.

1) **$** - Everything after the $ is interpreted as a variable name. It works if the $ is at the end of the password. Assumes there is no argument provided and generates password.

```
foo $ABC123abc
Valid password is X2Q$fsc2Bx

foo ABC123abc$
ABC123abc$ is a valid password
```

2) **#** - If placed at the beginning of the argument, the rest gets commented out.  A password is generated since it assumes no argument was provided.

```
foo #ABC123abc
Valid password is *vhkJT2j

foo  ABC1#23abc
ABC1#23abc is a valid password
```

3) **&** - Runs in background and evaluates only what is before the & character.

```
foo ABC1&23abc
ABC1 is not a valid password
```

I realize that everything works if I escape or single quote the argument:

```
foo '$ABC123abc'
$ABC123abc is a valid password

foo '#ABC123abc'
#ABC123abc is a valid password

foo 'ABC1&23abc'
ABC1&23abc is a valid password
```

I've been informed, however, that it is possible to have it run properly without the use of single quotes or escape of characters, all within the confines of the script.  I'm wondering if such a solution is possible, or if I am being sent on a wild goose chase.

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Assuming your script is `foo` then you were misinformed. You cannot handle special characters, etc. like that in your argument inside the script. They have been (mis)handled by the shell before you ever see them.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14922730/how-to-interpret-special-characters-in-command-line-argument-in-c/14924332#14924332 (which is perhaps a better duplicate; specifies "in C", but if you can't do it in C, you can't do it in any other language either).

Comment: Thank you both for your responses (and yes, foo was meant to be the script name).